# What's the purpose of 'instagram password cracker tools/hacker tools' websites?

Tags: attacks, web

There are over 9000 websites on the web claiming that they can hack Instagram accounts. In reality, none of them does what they say they do.

So, What's their purpose?

These website owners do know that their websites don't work, then why do they add more complexity to their site by adding 'human verification surveys and installing particular app things?

Why do these human verification steps say to install genuine apps like TikTok, unacademy, Facebook, Instagram etc?

Do corporations like TikTok, unacademy, Facebook, Instagram pay money to get their ads placed on these websites?

Comment: *"Why aren't search engines removing or stopping these websites from getting created, even after being equipped with such high AI?"* - search engines don't stop any websites from being created. What they do is to help find things which were already created.

Comment: *"is it ethical for advertising platforms like google ads (Just an example) to place ads on these Sharn/Bogus websites?"* - that not how ads in the web work. There is no tight control on what sites and which content ads are placed and there are many small (and sometimes shady) companies involved in the business. See also [Malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising).

Comment: *"Are programmers' financial condition so bad that they are employing these techniques for minimum livelihood"* - where do you think all this malware, phishing ... comes from. Programmers are no better people: if money can be made the easy way, enough of them will do it. Anyway, I find your question too broad and not a good fit here. And it is based on several wrong assumptions.

Comment: Hey mac,  Thanks for answering few questions. As of your concern, I'm layman. Never mind. Yeah, I too feel this list a ramblin' one. So could just explain me  the business model of these websites and motive of these website owners.

Comment: Just playing around with the first hit I got it looks like it is intended to grab users personal data, do "surveys" etc, i.e. just similar to "free iphone" etc scam. So the business model seems to be pretty clear here for me.

Comment: And what about install particular app and run it for 30 min etc things. Obviously the website owners would earn some commission. But what about  the parties placing ads. Like I see "Install Instagram to access details" on a website which says we would hack instagram.

Comment: Also, for example [instapwn.com]  this website asks users to pay money for viewing details.Who is governing authority for transactions like this?

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea of the web. It is not a tightly controlled and regulated place. Its not like a small village where everybody watches and trust the other. Its more like a huge city, with lots of good stuff but also lots of dirt. It provides lots of opportunities for both good and bad guys. There are enough places which are easily accessible but also dangerous.

Comment: I've tried to condense the post down to the relevant questions, the ones related to security and not ethics or quesses about what other people know, and the non-leading questions.

Answer (score 3):

One word: ***traffic***.

There are a lot of people searching for this topic, and we even get people here looking to "recover their account" on various platforms.

So, with all this traffic, people will seek to profit from it. Think of it like "clickbait". They entice people to visit their site and once the visitor is there, there are many things the site might do to profit from the visitor.

- some may attempt to infect the browser
- "human verification surveys" gather personal details on visitors that can be sold off to advertisers
- "install this" is a pure commission play or an attempt to infect the visitor's machine
- and advertising

Companies do not pay to get their ads displayed on these sites in particular. They pay *ad networks* to distribute their ads. These scam sites simply participate in the ad network to deliver the ads, just like any other site (even this one).